# Autoupdate not working automatically

Tags: google-play-store

I have set the Play store to autoupdate on wifi, and all the individual app settings allow autoupdate, but still I am being asked to approve individual updates for each app. When I approve them, there don't seem to be any changes to the permissions. What else could be the reason that autoupdate isn't working?

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S5 mini which recently updated to marshmallow (the autoupdate for apps was already not working before the OS update)

Comment: There are two levels of auto-update, general/global which is controlled by the Google Play Store settings, and, individual auto-update which is of course set individually for the application. They may be set to conflict with one another, or to be compatible. When they conflict (like global:ON, and individual:OFF, Or vice-versa), the dialog will be expected to appear. Check to see the settings (general+individual), for the apps in question, agree.

Comment: If I go into the Play store, under Settings, in the category General, it says "autoupdate over wifi only". If I go to a specific app (e.g. youtube) and click the 3 bars in the top right it shows autoupdate ticked. Could I be missing something or looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Is your WiFi available at all times? Some devices turn off WiFi as a performance/power saving measure. The Google Updates cannot be scheduled to a particular time, so it must be available when it wants to do updates to your device. Otherwise it bypasses you until a further attempt next time.

Comment: Yes, I'm connected to wifi more or less constantly.

Comment: One thing which might matter (but shouldn't): I set the data usage for the play store to restrict background data. It says "wifi will be used if available".

Comment: Quote: "Yes, I'm connected to wifi more or less constantly." I'm convinced the problem is related to the "less" in your statement. Like, if your Wifi disconnects when your screen sleeps, and similar cases.

Comment: In the advanced settings for WiFi, it says "keep wifi on during sleep: always". Is there another setting I could check?

Comment: I meant "less" in the sense that when I go out I don't have wifi. But autoupdate sometimes doesn't work even when I'm at home.